# Is ochel nefesh permissible when Yom Tov falls on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, ochel-nefesh, orach-chaim

On Yom Tov, there are certain examples of melacha being permitted that would otherwise be prohibited, based on it being permissible for the holiday’s need. My question is, does the law permitting melacha for ochel nefesh apply when Yom Tov falls on Shabbat?

Or to rephrase, is ochel nefesh a positive heter for melacha for holiday needs, which includes permitting it on Shabbat or only the lack of negative prohibitions for the melacha, under which case Shabbat’s prohibitions would prohibit it regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ramba'n on Vayikra (23:2) says:

> והזכיר השבת במועדי ה' אשר תקראו אותם מקראי קודש... וירמוז עוד בכאן כי גם בבואו באחד מן המועדים לא תדחה לעשות בה אוכל נפש...
>
> He mentioned the Sabbath among *the appointed seasons which ye shall proclaim to be holy convocations*, [although the Sabbath is not proclaimed by the children of Israel, since its sanctity has been affirmed by G-d and is fixed throughout the generations],... He further alludes here [to the law that even] when the Sabbath falls on one of [the days of] the festivals, we must not suspend [the law of the Sabbath] so that the preparation of food bw permitted on it [as it is on a festival day when it falls on a weekday, but instead it is prohibited].

So the Ramba'n learns from here that on Shabbos which is Yom Tov, ochel nefesh is prohibited.

Comment: Note the ochel nefesh there is only prohibited qua shabbat, not qua yom tov

Comment: @DoubleAA, that is actually discussed here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://beinenu.com/system/files/alonim/921_15_83.pdf%3Fdownload%3D1&ved=2ahUKEwintcyIxtGDAxV6RqQEHZ4TC64QFnoECCUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw221cGQTIDyubzX0ZsPJ0sA though I don't know how reliable it is